# alsa selecting line-in with a plugin filter

Tags: audio, alsa

I have an audio source connected to "line-in" of my sound card. The volume is too high and I would like to filter the input via some sort of plugin (maybe a LADSPA limiter or something) to reduce the volume to match the output volume of other sources. Does anyone know of a way to do this in .asoundrc or some other method?